# Creating Binary search tree for morse code

Tags: java, tree

So for an assignment that we got we have to create a binary search tree in one of our classes representing the morse code one (this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#/media/File:Morse_code_tree3.png) in a method private void buildTree(). To help us along he gave us an array filled with all of the characters which i'll show in a second. In the method we have to create the tree through reference to a node already declared called topMostNode. The array of char values is here

```
private static final char treeChars[] =
    { 'E', 'I', 'S', 'H', '5', '4', 'V', '3', 'U', 'F', UNUSED_CHAR, '2', 'A',
      'R', 'L', 'W', 'P', 'J', '1',
      'T', 'N', 'D', 'B', '6', 'X', 'K',
      'C', 'Y', 'M', 'G', 'Z', '7', 'Q', 'O', UNUSED_CHAR, '8', UNUSED_CHAR, '9', '0'
    };
```

He says there is a certain sequence we will have to use to put that array in the format of the earlier image in our tree, but I have been staring at it for the past few hours and honestly cannot find out what it is. It seems impossible because the array just skips over unprintable characters that aren't wanted in the tree unless they're needed to point to other valid characters, and these invalid chars at randomly placed at the bottom of the tree so there is no pattern for knowing when to just not point at the dit or dah portion of the node. How do I do this? I have honestly considered just hardcoding every value in at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure how this works but I am guessing from the array you want to build the tree and looking at it shows that it is a `depth first tree`. It is a rather simply concept that you can translate into an array for that tree quite easily; there are depth first tree traversal codes laying around.

Once you have the array, you can get the left or right child of the current node by using `2*(node)` for the left child and `2*(node)+1` for the right child.

Comment: Yes, I want to put the array that he provided into a tree, which can only be referenced from one node that we have 'topMostNode', and the tree must look like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#/media/File:Morse_code_tree3.png

Comment: The problem with your solution is that some nodes in the middle of the tree only point to one or two values because some of the bottom most nodes are invalid characters that he doesn't want in the tree, thus aren't in the array. The other problem is that the array isn't organized in the way to do the 2*node/+1 method. At least I think, maybe you're right and i'm just not seeing it

Comment: I see what you are saying, from the array provided, it is not a complete tree so using a depth first traversal wouldn't guarantee you'll know where the nodes stop. Are there any other specifications on the assignment that might help figuring out where the node should end?

Comment: all he says about the buildTree method is "In order to make the tree the same as the tree shown on the Wikipedia
site, which is the most efficient tree structure, the sequence of adding Morse Code sequences
to the table is a specific sequence. To aid you, I have provided a partial Class file for you that
provides the sequence as a class static final String array and a "parallel" array of the equivalent
ASCII characters; i.e. the "value" of the node for the associated Morse Code in the String array."

Comment: Yeah either I am overlooking the question or it isn't possible. Unless he specifies when a node can either have a right or left child, a tree traversal is not possible. I would try to contact him to specify what he is asking for and for now, just disregard the array given, create a new one that is an based off the tree and create the binary search tree algorithm.